# Flutter build error. Issue with flutter webview plugin

Tags: flutter

I have added the flutter webview plugin but its causing problems. Its giving some error when building the project. I tried to delete the cache and rebuild the project but it didn't work.

I just started learning flutter and can't find a solution to this problem.

Below is the error I am getting.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':flutter_webview_plugin:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>     Unable to find source java class: 'C:\Users\personal\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_webview_plugin-0.0.9+1\android\src\main\java\com\flutter_webview_plugin\WebviewActivity.java' because it does not belong to any of the source dirs: '[C:\Users\personal\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_webview_plugin-0.1.5\android\src\main\java, C:\Users\personal\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_webview_plugin-0.1.5\android\src\debug\java, C:\Users\personal\Documents\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_newz\build\flutter_webview_plugin\generated\source\r\debug, C:\Users\personal\Documents\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_newz\build\flutter_webview_plugin\generated\source\buildConfig\debug, C:\Users\personal\Documents\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_newz\build\flutter_webview_plugin\generated\source\aidl\debug, C:\Users\personal\Documents\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_newz\build\flutter_webview_plugin\generated\source\rs\debug]'
>
> BUILD FAILED in 54s
>   Finished with error: Gradle build failed: 1

Comment: What Flutter version? What webview plugin version? Is this also in a newly created project?

Comment: the webview is 0.1.5 and the flutter is 23.2.1

Comment: I was using an older version of flutter but I updated it. Still getting another error now.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Comment: `23.2.1` doesn't look like a Flutter version number.

Comment: Do you get the same result if you start with a new project with `flutter create`?

Comment: 23.2.1 flutter plugin version for android studio. Not sure if its the same as the flutter version

Comment: I have created other projects as well but this is the first time I am getting this error in flutter.

Comment: `flutter --version` on command line

Comment: flutter version 0.2.3

Comment: I was using flutter plugins that were not latest. I updated all the plugins to the latest version and its working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using other plugins for firebase auth, firebase analytics, google sign in , webview, ect. Updating all the plugins to the latest version solved the problem.